# JavaFX stage appearing blank

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to build a simple `JavaFX` application using `fxml` and the start method looks like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("FenetreCaisse.fxml"));
        Scene scene = root.getScene();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and when i try to run it i get a `<code>NullPointerException</code>` at the `scene.getStylesheets()...` line

I tried commenting that line since I don't have any code in the "application.css" file but when I ran the code, All i got was a white blank window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
root.getScene()
```

returns the current scene in which `root` is contained, which is null if it hasn't been added to a scene. So you are setting the stage's scene to null.

Use

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

Obviously remove the line that sets the stylesheet if you don't have a stylesheet.